# Char array from cin

Tags: c++

I have a function in c++ that accepts
char[] arg. If char[] is hardcode like

```
char t[] = { 0x41, 0x54, 0x2b, 0x4d, 
0x53, 0x4c, 0x53, 0x45, 0x43, 0x55, 
0x52, 0x3d, 0x31, 0x2c, 0x30 }
```

it works. I need to be able to get the char[] from cin, the data from cin will be ascii AT+MSLSECUR=1,0 and need to convert it to equivalent of the hardcoded char[] i show above

I dont know where to start i tried simply making cin read to char[] but doesnt seem to work char[] data is wrong

I am new to this so please forgive my lack of knowledge

Comment: Need more information on what you are doing that isn't working. Code example highly recommended. [mcve] would be preferred. Shot in the dark: If you `char t[];` without initializing it, the compiler has no idea how big to make `t`.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Can you please try to be more specific? And what have you tried? Could you please show us a [mcve] of your attempt to us? Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And by the way, what's wrong with reading the input like any other string? As in `std::string t; std::cin >> t;`

Comment: If i read as std::string t; cin >> t;  then t is not equivalent to the char t[] {} example i gave and the function im sending it to doesnt accept std::string as the arg. I tried    char t[100]; string s; cin >> s; for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
 {
  t[i] = s.c_str()[i];
  
  
   }  however that is not correct it doesnt match the hardcode example i gave and function returns error stating wrong data recieved. I am able to show the actual code in the function as it is part of proprietary code

Comment: It's seems you're misunderstanding how a string of characters is stored in memory. May I suggest you try something something like `std::string t; std::cin >> t; /* just like suggested before, but now lets print the contents of the string */ for (char const c : t) std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(c) << ' '; std::cout << '\n';`. The loop will print out the characters in the string, with their hexadecimal representation.

Comment: To help you understand a little better, a `char` is basically a small-sized integer. The value of the that integer is the standard system encoded value of the corresponding character. With an ASCII system, then `'A'` will be equal to the integer value `65` which is the decimal representation of the hexadecimal value `0x41`. Displaying as a character, decimal, hexadecimal (or even the octal value `0101`) is just a matter of presentation. Deep down in the memory of the computer it's still going to be the binary bits `01000001`.

Comment: Also, if you read it into a `std::string`, then you have the good fortune to know have an array of characters (however you want to represent them) and its length right there for you. If you need to pass it along to some other function, then you can use `t.c_str()` to get a pointer to the first element of that array (similar to what would happen if you used plain `t` in the example in your question) and the length through `t.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's that what you are asking for :

```
std::string input ;
std::cin << input ;
char *YourCharArray = new char [ input.size() + 1 ] ;
strcpy(YourCharArray , input.c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you gamer the function does accept that however incorrect data, data doesnt match example char t[] i gave when enter AT+MSLSECUR=1,0 in cin